# How best to implement user selectable variables in web application

Tags: java, web-applications, variables, user-input

I have a Java based web-application and a new requirement to allow Users to place variables into text fields that are replaced when a document or other output is produced. How have others gone about this?

I was thinking of having a pre-defined set of variables such as :
`@BOOKING_NUMBER@`
`@INVOICE_NUMBER@`

Then when a user enters some text they can specify a variable inline (select it from a modal or similar). For example:

*"This is some text for Booking `@BOOKING_NUMBER@` that is needed by me"*

When producing some output (eg. PDF) that uses this text, I would do a regex and find all variables and replace them with the correct value:

*"This is some text for Booking 10001 that is needed by me"*

My initial thought was something like Freemarker but I think that is too complex for my Users and would require them to know my DataModel (eww).

Thanks for reading!

D.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at java.text.MessageFormat - particularly the format method - as this is designed for exactly what you are looking for.

i.e.

```
MessageFormat.format("This is some text for booking {0} that is needed by me, for use with invoice {1}", bookingNumber, invoiceNumber);
```

You may even want to get the template text from a resource bundle, to allow for support of multiple languages, with the added ability to cope with the fact that {0} and {1} may appear in a different order in some languages.

UPDATE:
I just read your original post properly, and noticed the comment about the PDF.
This suggest that the template text is going to be significantly larger than a line or two.

In such cases, you may want to explore something like [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/) which seems better suited for this purpose - this comment is based solely on initial investigations, as I've not used it in anger.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a similiar replacement token system before.  I personally like something like.

[MYVALUE]

As it is easy for the user to type, and then I just use replacements to swap out the tokens for the real data.

Comment: Too complex. It sounds like reinventing the wheel when you already have MessageFormat that handles it.

Comment: But expecting a regular user to remember that {0} is name and that {1} is booking number is NOT practical, thus the need for something that can make more sense to the user, thus my recommendation.

Comment: StringTemplate addresses the naming issues, but probably introduces other issues. Further investigation required.